# Using SELECT statement inside an IF Else condition in JasperReports SQL query in JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have the following sample query:

```sql
     IF(1=1)
      Select  top 10 * from Person

     ELSE
      Select top 10 * from Person where Id < 20
```

When i create a report with above query using *iReport*, the report works fine.

But when i upload the same report to *JasperReports Server* and try to run the report, it is throwing the below  error.

```
ERROR Validator,report1 subreports #1:493 - Invalid SQL:An error has occurred. 
Please contact your system administrator. (6632), 
SQL: IF(1=1)Select  top 10 * from PersonELSESelect top 10 * from Person where Id < 20.
```

Does *JasperReports Server* supports IF..Else conditions outside the SELECT statement?

Do any one know about this error?

Comment: @AlexK Thanks for your reply. Initially i thought the same and verified the query and found that it is proper. Now i even tried putting just  the if condition as i previously mentioned, but this time i got the same error with " ' SQL: IF(1=1)Select  top 10 * from Person '". I figured that the report that i uploaded was wrong when i tested the scenario with SQL " 'IF(1=1)
   Select  top 10 * from Person' ". So now i haved edited the question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for around 4 days, i found a solution.

Jasper Server allows the SQL queries that starts with only "SELECT" keyword. So in order to make other queries work, we have to modify a regular expression of "Validator.ValidSQL" that is present in "webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/classes/esapi/security-config.properties/validation.properties" location.

I have modified this regular expression to support 'IF' conditions and made it work.

Got this solution from jasper community forum:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/800208/stored-procedures-works-ireport-does-not-work-jasperserver.